# Help with Make error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

When I run make I get an error:

```
root@vagrantup:~/npm-1285112852/scripts# ./install.sh 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  568k  100  568k    0     0   267k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  466k
node cli.js cache clean
make: node: Command not found
make: *** [uninstall] Error 127
```

I have installed gcc. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> node cli.js cache clean
> make: node: Command not found
> ```

The Makefile is trying to run the command `node cli.js cache clean`, but can't find a program called `node` in your PATH.  To fix this, install whatever package provides the `node` program.  The program you're trying to compile should contain a file called `README` or `INSTALL` or something like that that tells you what the dependencies are to compile it.